# Converting array string to arraylist without nesting it in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
static sample(String attachment){

// attachment: ["filename.png", "filename.png"]

List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(attachment);

// attachment after converting to list: [["filename.png", "filename.png"]]

  for(String getarr: arr) {
   //iterate over filenames 
  }

}
```

Tried looping twice but the first loop result is string so i can't loop in for the second time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you be more specific?

Comment: `String attachment`, are you sure?

Comment: Looks like you are having a comma separated `String` which needs to be `split()` first... Basically like `List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(attachment.split(","));` or similar...

Comment: I think there may be strings attached.

Comment: i want to convert my array string to arraylist but converting  makes nested array, is there a way to convert without nesting it, by preserving its structure?

Comment: @QUIET --> *`String attachment`* <--, *are you sure* it's a `String` array?

Comment: Your problem may lay somewhere else. You expect an array but got a string. Perhaps you should check the code that calls this method and see why it converts the original collection or array into a string before sending to you. It shouldn't. You should get the original array instead of trying to parse the string.

Comment: @deHaar not good for this, got this error message saying "cannot invoke split(string) on the array type string[]"

Comment: @akuzminykh yes, it is string. displayed the datatype.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it is definitely a string because i'm getting it from json, attachment is the one of the property of json that i'm passing to that method so i'm converting it so i can iterate the filename. actually i'm creating an emailer API which accepts multiple attachment.

Comment: Please supply the actual JSON (add it to your question, not in a comment). Arrays in JSON are generally automatically parsed into either arrays or lists if you use a proper JSON parser. If the array appears as a string within the JSON, then whoever is sending the JSON is doing it wrong.

Comment: The you already have a `String[]` and there's no need to `split()`. Describe your problem a little more in detail, please...

Comment: thank you so much for your time. sorry for the vague description.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but taking the signature of the sample function at face value, some quick and dirty solution may be as follows. Of course, all these maps could be collapsed into one iteration only.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "[\"filename1.png\", \"filename2.png\", \"filename3.png\"]";
        List<String> attachments = splitAttachmentFilenames(s);

        attachments.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    static List<String> splitAttachmentFilenames(String attachment) {
        // attachment: ["filename.png", "filename.png"]
        String[] arr = attachment.split(",");
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList(arr);

        return l.stream()
                .map(String::trim)
                .map(s -> removeLeadingChar(s, '['))
                .map(s -> removeTrailingChar(s, ']'))
                .map(s -> removeLeadingChar(s, '"'))
                .map(s -> removeTrailingChar(s, '"'))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static String removeLeadingChar(String s, char c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        while (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(0) == c) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static String removeTrailingChar(String s, char c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        while (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == c) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figure it out. thanks for the feedback, i got an idea from it. from the source i make it comma separated string to pass and split the attachment then i loop it.

```
// attachment: "filename.png","filename.png"
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(attachment.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

If Ondřej Černoš answer is correct you can also use guava Splitter to split String:

```
String s = "[\"filename1.png\", \"filename2.png\", \"filename3.png\", \"\", ]";
List<String> attachments = Splitter.on(",") //string separator
                                   .trimResults(CharMatcher.anyOf("\" []")) //any characters you want to trim
                                   .omitEmptyStrings() //remove empty results
                                   .splitToList(s);  //and create list
```